# cannot iterate a kwargs input

Tags: python, class, iteration, keyword-argument

Heey everyone! It is my first time to post a question as I am practicing Python by myself. I am not sure if similar question has been asked, but I need some tips with using **kwargs and I look forward for a feedback from a smart, enthusisastic professional coder ;)

I created a class *FastFoodChain* and a method *add_food* that if you pass in multiple food names and prices as kwargs, they shall be added to the menu:

```
class FastFoodChain():

   def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name
       self.menu = None #type is a dictionary
       print(f"{name} established! Congrats!")
    
   def add_food(self, **foods): # Add a few foods from the product
    
       for food,price in foods.items():

           if food in self.menu.keys():
               return f"{food} is already in the menu"

           else:
               #self.menu[food] = price
               self.menu.setdefault(food,price)
               return f"{food} added to the menu"

McDonalds = FastFoodChain("McDonalds")
McDonalds.menu = {'fries': 3, 'chicken_nuggets': 4, 'cheeseburger': 4.5, 'cola': 2.5, 'chicken_burger': 5}
```

However, this function is not iterating **foods but only Big_mac, the first argument is updated to the menu:

```
McDonalds.add_food(Big_Mac = 6, Spicy_chicken_burger=4)
```

Any suggestions could be helpful. :)) Thanks in advance.
Leo

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask], which has tips like how to write a good title. Personally, I'd write something more like "Why is only the first argument being used?" It's also important to note that SO is meant to be like a reference, not a forum, so chit-chat like "I'm new here" and such should be kept to a minimum.

Comment: BTW, instead of `self.menu = None`, it'd probably be better to pass `menu` into `__init__`, that way you won't forget to set it. You could also add type hinting instead of that comment. So, something like: `def __init__(self, name: str, menu: dict): ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `return` statement, which automatically ends the function. You could simply replace the two `return` statements with the `print` function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both `if` and `else` end with a `return`, so the loop will exit after the first time.

Here's a suggestion to fix that.

```py
class FastFoodChain():
    
   def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name
       self.menu = None #type is a dictionary
       print(f"{name} established! Congrats!")
    
   def add_food(self, **foods): # Add a few foods from the product
    
       for food,price in foods.items():

           if food in self.menu.keys():
               print(f"{food} is already in the menu")

           else:
               #self.menu[food] = price
               self.menu.setdefault(food,price)
               print(f"{food} added to the menu")

McDonalds = FastFoodChain("McDonalds")
McDonalds.menu = {'fries': 3, 'chicken_nuggets': 4, 'cheeseburger': 4.5, 'cola': 2.5, 'chicken_burger': 5}
McDonalds.add_food(Big_Mac = 6, Spicy_chicken_burger=4)
print(McDonalds.__dict__)
```